# Custom exposed filter for year in date field with ajax

Tags: views

I am trying to create a custom exposed filter which would be a select field with years (2015-2025).
This would filter the result with the year of the date they are created.
I followed this tutorial https://www.flocondetoile.fr/blog/filter-content-year-views-drupal-8
But here there is no solution for ajax submission, so the page does not refresh and the filter does not apply.

Currently I have this year as a contextual filter and the form field in the hook_form_views_exposed_form_alter():

```
$options = [
    'all' => t('- All -'),
    '2015' => '2015',
    '2016' => '2016',
    '2017' => '2017',
    '2018' => '2018',
    '2019' => '2019',
    '2020' => '2020',
    '2021' => '2021',
    '2022' => '2022',
    '2023' => '2023',
    '2024' => '2024',
    '2025' => '2025',
  ];

  $form['year'] = [
    '#title' => t('By year'),
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => $options,
    '#size' => NULL,
    '#default_value' => 'all',
  ];
```

Is there a possibility for the filter to work with ajax submission?

Comment: You can try create views custom filter https://www.webomelette.com/creating-custom-views-filter-drupal-8

Answer (score 0):

You can use this custom filter to filter by year:
https://github.com/DarkteK/d8-views-custom-filter/tree/master/d8_filters

Just change the years you want to use in the file 'ViewsYearsFilter.php'

This will work with Ajax

Answer (score -1):

I believe Views [Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) can achieve this: `What else can I do with BEF?: Provide instant feedback by updating the View using AJAX whenever an exposed filter is changed`